# MakeFile C++ problem only have .Object files

Tags: c++, makefile

As the title say i have a problem compiling so i have my makefile who compile great my .cpp , then I have .o in the bin directory but after that its off I stay with my .o files and nothing change ,
It seems it doesnt take into account the few lines i wrote after and cant have my .exe

I think its something to do with the last lines because all the compile thing from .cpp to .o works great

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#

#   MAKEFILE of the Radio Simulation Program

#

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# 03/05/21  Creation

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------





# Define options and paths

CFLAGS = -Wall -O

SRCDIR = ./Src

INCDIR = ./Inc

BINDIR = ./Bin

TARGET = ./Bin



# Program name

EXE_PROG = $(BINDIR)/simradio.exe

all = $(EXE_PROG)



all: $(BINDIR)/SimMain.o $(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o  $(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o $(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o $(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o  $(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o 



# Source file compilations



$(BINDIR)/SimMain.o: $(SRCDIR)/SimMain.cpp

    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/SimMain.o -c $(SRCDIR)/SimMain.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

    



$(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o: $(SRCDIR)/classConfigCtx.cpp

    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o -c $(SRCDIR)/classConfigCtx.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)



$(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o: $(SRCDIR)/ClassRadMgr.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o -c $(SRCDIR)/ClassRadMgr.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)



$(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o: $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSlot.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o -c $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSlot.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)



$(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o: $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSrv.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o -c $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSrv.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)



$(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o: $(SRCDIR)/SupSrv.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o -c $(SRCDIR)/SupSrv.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

    

$(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o: $(SRCDIR)/AppliMsg.cpp

    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o -c $(SRCDIR)/AppliMsg.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

    



$(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o: $(SRCDIR)/AgentSNMP.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o -c $(SRCDIR)/AgentSNMP.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)
    



# Object files list

OBJ_LIST =  $(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o $(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o $(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o $(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o $(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o $(BINDIR)/SimMain.o

help:
    echo $(OBJ_LIST)



# Erase the former binary files

mrproper: clean

    rm -f $(EXE_PROG):$(OBJ_LIST)

    g++ -g -o $(EXE_PROG) $(OBJ_LIST)
```

Comment: The first target in your `Makefile` is `all:` which builds only the object files. Why do you think that the shown Makefile should also build your executable?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for your feedback , I actually discovered makefile not a long time ago so i'm pretty bad , I thought rm -f $(EXE_PROG):$(OBJ_LIST) would do the job. Do you have any Idea of what to write to make my .object file an exe ? I have also the SimMain.object (My main file) as you can see

Comment: What you're looking for is a completely separate command, `make $(OBJ_LIST)`, although there are far better ways to do this.

Comment: I supposed its not as simple as write "make objlist" in my programm ? thanks @SamVarshavchik

Comment: No, this wouldn't go into your program, but rather your Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below code/reference example which will compile-link and generate the end executable.OFcourse, the dependency check can also be added in this

```
# Define options and paths
CFLAGS = -Wall -O
SRCDIR = ./Src
INCDIR = ./Inc
BINDIR = ./Bin
TARGET = ./Bin

# Program name
EXE_PROG = $(BINDIR)/simradio.exe

all: $(EXE_PROG)

# Source file compilations

$(BINDIR)/SimMain.o: $(SRCDIR)/SimMain.cpp
    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/SimMain.o -c $(SRCDIR)/SimMain.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

$(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o: $(SRCDIR)/classConfigCtx.cpp
    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o -c $(SRCDIR)/classConfigCtx.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

$(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o: $(SRCDIR)/ClassRadMgr.cpp
    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o -c $(SRCDIR)/ClassRadMgr.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

$(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o: $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSlot.cpp
    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o -c $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSlot.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

$(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o: $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSrv.cpp
    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o -c $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSrv.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

$(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o: $(SRCDIR)/SupSrv.cpp
    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o -c $(SRCDIR)/SupSrv.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

$(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o: $(SRCDIR)/AppliMsg.cpp
    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o -c $(SRCDIR)/AppliMsg.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

$(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o: $(SRCDIR)/AgentSNMP.cpp
    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o -c $(SRCDIR)/AgentSNMP.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

# Object files list
OBJ_LIST =  $(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o $(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o $(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o $(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o $(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o $(BINDIR)/SimMain.o

help:
    echo $(OBJ_LIST)

$(EXE_PROG): $(OBJ_LIST)
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_LIST) -o $@
    echo "build successful"
```

Comment: @aetopiu can you please check if this works for you